# Website scroll not working on SAFARI

Tags: css

I have a site here missnationglobal.com. Scrolling works fine on Chrome and other browsers except safari.

I checked the css markup for the site and don't seem to be able to figure out what is causing it, here's some code:

```
html {
  height: 100% !important;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;

  overflow:scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
  -webkit-overflow-y: auto; /* added css prefix for safari */

}
body {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try with **overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;**

Comment: Hi, tried it, unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Well here's the thing, I inherited this wordpress site. I tried removing all the css in style.css, but even that doesn't fix it. I tried changing the theme, and disabling all plugins, but that did not help at all either.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this same issue. I believe this is more of a limitation of Safari than it is an issue of your creation. The only "tricks" I was able to find online are

```
overflow-y: scroll; 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

I have added this to my container and child elements with no luck. I even added a pseudo element that was slightly bigger than the container hoping to trigger the scroll-bar on load, but this did not work either.

Lastly, I tried adding scroll-bar styles to the container hoping that would force it, but as you probably can guess: no dice.

I reached out directly to Safari technical support, and I hope to have an updated answer within the next couple of days. If anyone has come up with a working solution, please let me know!